# Need some help parsing a string in C

Tags: c, string

Using fgets, I have read in a line from a text file.  The line may be something like this:

`# O^6+ + H -> O^5+ + H^+`

Or it may be this:

`# Mg^12+ + H -> Mg^11+ + H^+`

or this:

`# Ne^10+ + He -> Ne^9+ + He^+`

Or a multitude of other possibilities.

I am trying to extract the ion, the charge and the atom terms from the string.

I tried something like this:

`sscanf(line,"# %2s^%d+ + %2s",cs->ION,&(cs->Z),cs->ATOM);`

I also tried this:

`sscanf(line,"# %[^^]s^%d+ + %2s",cs->ION,&(cs->Z),cs->ATOM);`  Because I was picking up the '^' character.

I just can't seem to get this to work for every case.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I would just parse the string using loops and the isalpha(), isdigit() functions.  A bit crude but completely flexible.  Also, you might want to add the c tag.

Comment: Pattern of analysis is not clear.

Comment: Use the `' '` separator to break the major tokens like `'O^6+'`, `'->'` and `'+'`.  Then scan the elements as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your try with the format string

```
"# %[^^]s^%d+ + %2s"
```

was almost right, except that after the `%[^^]` there has to be no `s`, i. e.

```
"# %[^^]^%d+ + %2s"
```

works.